# How to send a iCal invite with Mailgun Rest API coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, gmail, icalendar, mailgun, coldfusion-10

`I am setting up mailing functionality in my website using [mailgun](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api_reference.html). I can send mail using the mailgun API, both text and HTML content. However, I need to sent mail with calendar attachment, but couldn't find any better way to do that in ColdFusion. Could any one please help me out?

```
<cfhttp result="result" method="POST" charset="utf-8"
   url="https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox0000000000000000000.mailgun.org/messages" >

    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" 
       value="Basic #ToBase64("api:***********************************79")#" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="from" 
         value="postmaster@sandbox0000000000000000000.mailgun.org" >
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="to" value="me@test.com"  />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="subject" value="mail content"  />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="text" value="mail content from test account"  />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="attachment" value="my path"  />
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: Tip, tag based code like CFML has to be indented four spaces or it won't be visible.  You can also use the code button `{}` in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `invite.ics` calendar file, I first wrote this file into a folder and so I can provide the path to `cfhttpparam` for the name `attachment`. After sending the mail I just removed that from my folder. It is simple as that for any type of file.

```
<cfhttp result="result" url="https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox0000000000000000000.mailgun.org/messages" method="POST">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Basic #ToBase64("api:***********************************79")#" />
    <cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="from" value="test@gmail.com">
    <cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="to" value="test@test.com">
    <cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="subject" value="attachment test">
    <cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="text" value="Hello">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="html" value="<html>Testing with text/calendar******* type</html>"  />
    <cfhttpparam type="file" name="attachment" file="#yourattachementfilepath here#" >
</cfhttp>
```